# LazyInitializationException with @Transactional annotation in MessageConverter

Tags: model-view-controller, hibernate, spring

I have a REST-service exposed through Spring-MVC. I have a particular method which is correctly mapped and called through a HTTP-call. My Spring application contains the `HibernateTransactionManager` and transactions are configured through `@Transactional`-annotations. I annotated the method like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<SomeObject> start(....)
```

Whenever I call the HTTP-method I a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` from my `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` which is bound in my application context. Is the `@Transactional` annotation valid for the `MessageConverter` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your converter class is obviously reading a field that's configured to be collected lazily in your Hibernate configuration.

Two possible solutions:

- Expand your transactional method to include the converter method.
- Edit your Hibernate configuration to eagerly fetch the field that's responsible of the `LazyInitializationException`. (This field can for example be a part of a relationship between two tables in the database.)

Comment: I already fixed my problem by doing what was your first proposal. Actually the problem was that another tool that I used for mapping objects, copyed persistbags instead of the real collections...

Comment: Iam facing the same problem here,Please, how did you that? how did you expand your transactional method?

Answer (score 2):

`LazyInitializationException` means that your hibernate `Session` is closed at the time you try to read uninitialized data on your entity.

You can fix this by:

- either extending the lifetime of the session (using [OpenSessionInView](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)
- pre-initialize the entity in your service method, using `Hibernate.initialize(entity)`